# iOS rotation issues

Tags: ios, rotation

Afternoon all,

Has anyone worked with collection views in iOS with an image fullscreen and horizontal paging?

I am currently experiencing difficulties when I rotate to landscape. I have read many posts on this subject on here and can't seem to find anything that helps the issue.

When I rotate the item i was looking at changes and the images are displaced on the screen. Is there anything short of turning orientations off that will fix this?

Thanks

ps if you need to see any of the code let me know and i'll edit my question

Code used:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_startingIndexPath) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollView.bounds.size.width / 2) / scrollView.bounds.size.width) + 1;
        if (currentIndex < [self.marbleImages count]) {
            self.title = self.marbleImages[currentIndex][@"name"];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.itemSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.startingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: do you handle the rotation event?

Comment: Not directly as I haven't had to before, I have edited my question to show the code I am using.